# MySql Index Fill Factor?

Tags: mysql, indexing, fillfactor

How do you specify the Fill Factor when creating an index in MySql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

However, it is an 'accepted' feature request for version 6.x:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18178

So, don't hold your breath on seeing it any time soon.

Comment: Well that sucks... but oh well!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using InnoDB, it seems like this is only supported at database level, not index level.

The setting is called `innodb_fill_factor` and defaults to `100` see
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fill_factor for more details.